# Object variable or with block variable not set error occurs in second iteration of for loop

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I've the below code that I'm using in outlook to download an attachment from a list of emails.

The code works fine for the first iteration of the loop, but on the second iteration it errors with `Run-time error '91' Object variable or With block variable not set` at the step where it is attempting to save the file to a temporary folder on the desktop (i.e. the line `wb.SaveAs FileFormat:=51, FileName:=xlNameAndPath`).

From reading the documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa264506.aspx) and some testing, it seems that the issue is actually being caused in the first iteration of the loop by `wb.close`, this sets `wb` to nothing, which then causes the error in the second iteration.

If i'm right then my question is how to "Respecify a reference for the object variable"?

```
Sub SaveExcels()

Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace: Set objNS = GetNamespace("MAPI")
Dim olFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Set olFolder = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Dim Item As Object
Dim objAttachments As Outlook.Attachments

For Each Item In olFolder.Items

    If TypeOf Item Is Outlook.MailItem Then

        Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem: Set oMail = Item

        ' Check it contains an attachment
        Set objAttachments = oMail.Attachments
        lngCount = objAttachments.Count

        ' Check its from the right company
        senderCheck = InStr(oMail.SenderEmailAddress, "company.com")

        ' Check that it is the right email type
        subjectCheck = InStr(oMail.Subject, "TYPE")

        ' Check whether its the latest weeks data
        receivedDate = DateValue(oMail.ReceivedTime)
        todaysDate = DateValue(Now())
        dateDifference = todaysDate - receivedDate

        If lngCount > 0 And senderCheck > 0 And subjectCheck > 0 And dateDifference <= 7 Then

            ' Get the file name
            strFile = objAttachments.Item(1).FileName
            ' Debug.Print strFile

            strFolderpath = "D:\Users\" & Environ("Username") & "\Desktop\temp\"

            ' Combine with the path to the Temp folder.
            strFileIncPath = strFolderpath & strFile
            ' Debug.Print strFile

            ' Save the attachment as a file.
            objAttachments.Item(1).SaveAsFile strFileIncPath

            ' Extract the files into the newly created folder
            Set oApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
            oApp.NameSpace(strFolderpath).CopyHere oApp.NameSpace(strFileIncPath).Items

            ' Delete the zip file
            Kill strFileIncPath

            ' Open the excel file
            Dim xlApp As Object
            Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

            xlApp.Application.Visible = True
            xlName = Replace(strFile, ".ZIP", "")
            xlNameTemp = xlName & "_00000.xls"
            xlNameAndPath = strFolderpath & xlName
            Debug.Print xlNameAndPath

            xlApp.Workbooks.Open strFolderpath & xlNameTemp

            Dim wb As Workbook
            Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

            ' Save as unique name and close
            wb.SaveAs FileFormat:=51, FileName:=xlNameAndPath << ERROR

            ' Get rid of the old excel
            Kill strFolderpath & xlNameTemp

            ' Close the workbook
            wb.Close

        End If

    End If

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: In your "Set wb = ActiveWorkbook," can you use the debugger to see if ActiveWorkbook is valid? (BTW, where is ActiveWorkbook defined in the first place?)

Comment: @SandyGettings I assume Sam added a reference to the type library, "Microsoft Excel <version> Object Library" (VBA Editor, Tools | References).  That makes `Workbook` and similar types visible in `Dim` statements.  It also gives you the `ActiveWorkbook` global, along with `ActiveSheet` and the `xl*` constants.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(strFolderpath & xlNameTemp)
```

will do the job, per [the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194819.aspx).  (Not tested -YMMV!)